# Tkinter winfo on TabControl

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Python Tkinter Tab with a label on the second tab. I want to find the label's y and height parameters. Here is what I have done:

```
#! python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
main.geometry('450x400')

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(main)
tab1 = Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = Frame(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab Heading 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab Heading 2')

tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

Label(tab1,text="Label on Tab 1").place(x=20, y=40)

Label(tab2,text ="Label on Tab 2").pack(padx=20, pady=(0,30))
L = Label(tab2,text ="Another Tab2 Label")
L.pack()

#tab2.pack()
tab2.update()

print ( L.winfo_y(), L.winfo_height() )

main.mainloop()
```

As the code is written, the print statement prints 0, 1; a clearly incorrect result.
If I uncomment tab2.pack(), the print statement gives 51, 21; presumably the correct values for y and height. However, it also disables tab2. The Label on Tab2 moves to where the Heading was and tab2 is inaccessible even using the Tab key. How can I get the label parameters and have a working tab?

Comment: The widgets on `tab2` don't HAVE defined positions or sizes when `tab2` isn't the currently visible pane of the Notebook.  Doing `tab2.pack()` caused the Frame to cease to be a pane of the Notebook.  It's not clear why you need this information - could it perhaps be deferred until such time as `tab2` becomes visible?  (You can bind the `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` event to be informed of this.)

Comment: Thanks jasonharper. Python sometimes plays strange tricks on the unwary!. I do not need the information until the tab is visible. If I create the content only when the tab is made visible, I will repeat the operation rather than just at the setup. However, I might have to do just that!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found where is the problem.
The problem is'nt the tab2.pack().

In fact, the problem relies on the position of the "L" label when the tab2 is'nt selected. (do you follow me ?)
I'm not sure but I think the Label "L" is'nt visible, but it is actually on the screen when you have selected the tab1.

I have confirmed it by trying to print the position after one second after opening the window, and quickly go on the tab2 when opened. And it printed me "51 21".

But if I don't go on the tab2 after one second, it prints me "0 1".

So if you have understood what I have said, you can now try to fix your code ( I can't because I dont know what were your intentions were. Why did you want the position of the "L" label.)

Welcome

Comment: Thanks Akopa. I am sure you have found the problem. This is just a snippet of code with all context removed. The label L is one of many in a loop so I guessed that I need to use the same event handler. The x, y of the cursor are passed with the event and it seemed an easy way to identify the clicked widget in the event handler. I do not need the information until tab2 is visible but I then have to refresh the tab every time is is opened. I could (somehow) open with tab2 active but that stops another tab using the same technique in the future.

Comment: By making tab2 open first, the coordinates of the Label L are extracted correctly. Unfortunately I have discovered that the event x and y and relative to the label not the canvas. So my overall strategy of identifying the label clicked has failed. I have, however, learned a lot about tabs! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome ! I am happy to help